# Is there a web app for coordinating office hours with students?

Tags: webapp-rec

I am trying to find a time for office hours that accommodates all of my students.

Does there exist a web app that will let me determine, say, two different 1-hour blocks of time for which my students are all free for at least half of each hour? I've already determined that for every half-hour block of time, at least two students have a conflict (and so my naive algorithm for solving this problem doesn't work).

There are of course hacks to do this: I could have each student create a google calendar and add them all to one calendar. I am simply optimistic that someone has already implemented a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, try [Doodle](http://www.doodle.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if your students have Google accounts, but Google Calendar has a feature of organizing events and will show you the calendars for all participants in order to find a spot when everyone is free.